# PHP undefined variables on index name

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am testing a MySQL query and it is working in MySQL workbench:-

```
SELECT patient.patient_id,
patient.patient_name_en,
patient.nationality,
visit.visit_id,
visit.date_of_visit,
visit.visit_reason,
visit.consultation_type,
visit.patient_weight,
visit.patient_height,
visit.visit_status,
visit.clinic_id,
doctor_list.doctor_name,
nurse_list.nurse_name,
consultation.complication_name,
consultation.diagnosis_id,
consultation.consultation_result,
medication.med_name,
consultation_med.given_quantity,
consultation_med.medication_collector
from visit
LEFT JOIN patient ON patient.patient_id = visit.patient_id
LEFT JOIN consultation ON visit.visit_id=consultation.visit_id 
LEFT JOIN nurse_list ON consultation.nurse_list_id = nurse_list.nurse_list_id
LEFT JOIN doctor_list ON consultation.doctor_list_id = doctor_list.doctor_list_id
LEFT JOIN consultation_med ON consultation_med.consultation_id = consultation.consultation_id
LEFT JOIN med_pharmacy ON med_pharmacy.med_pharmacy_id = consultation_med.med_pharmacy_id
LEFT JOIN medication ON medication.med_id=med_pharmacy.med_id
WHERE visit.clinic_id='361' AND visit.visit_id = '188'
```

[image]

But when I added into a PHP file, and add binding variables to it, I am getting an error said:

> Notice: Undefined index: patient_id in

Here I added the file at the top of my page:

```
<?php
  include_once('../php/connection.php');
  include_once('../php/visitProfile.php');
?>
```

Then the `visitProfile.php`:-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_error', 1);
require_once('../php/connection.php');

$cid = $_SESSION['clinic_id'];
$vid = $_REQUEST['pid'];

$getVisitProfile = "SELECT patient.patient_id,
patient.patient_name_en,
patient.nationality,
visit.visit_id,
visit.date_of_visit,
visit.visit_reason,
visit.consultation_type,
visit.patient_weight,
visit.patient_height,
visit.visit_status,
visit.clinic_id,
doctor_list.doctor_name,
nurse_list.nurse_name,
consultation.complication_name,
consultation.diagnosis_id,
consultation.consultation_result,
medication.med_name,
consultation_med.given_quantity,
consultation_med.medication_collector
FROM visit
LEFT JOIN patient ON patient.patient_id = visit.patient_id
LEFT JOIN consultation ON visit.visit_id=consultation.visit_id 
LEFT JOIN nurse_list ON consultation.nurse_list_id = nurse_list.nurse_list_id
LEFT JOIN doctor_list ON consultation.doctor_list_id = doctor_list.doctor_list_id
LEFT JOIN consultation_med ON consultation_med.consultation_id = consultation.consultation_id
LEFT JOIN med_pharmacy ON med_pharmacy.med_pharmacy_id = consultation_med.med_pharmacy_id
LEFT JOIN medication ON medication.med_id=med_pharmacy.med_id
WHERE visit.clinic_id=:cid AND visit.visit_id = :vid";

$execGetVisitProfile = $conn->prepare($getVisitProfile);
$execGetVisitProfile->bindValue(':cid', $cid);
$execGetVisitProfile->bindValue(':vid', $vid);
$execGetVisitProfile->execute();

$res = $execGetVisitProfile->fetchAll();
?>
```

And when I try to echo the patient id:

```
<th >Patient ID</th><td><?php echo $res['patient_id'] ?></td>
```

I am getting  the error on it.

P.S. Please note that the query could return one array of multiple ones, but some information are the same in each array like the patient id.

**EDIT**

`var_dump result`:

> array (size=1)   0 => 
>       array (size=38)
>         'patient_id' => string '361-9001' (length=8)
>         0 => string '361-9001' (length=8)
>         'patient_name_en' => string 'X Y Z' (length=5)
>         1 => string 'X Y Z' (length=5)
>         'nationality' => string 'Syrian' (length=6)
>         2 => string 'Syrian' (length=6)
>         'visit_id' => string '188' (length=3)
>         3 => string '188' (length=3)
>         'date_of_visit' => string '2017-07-20' (length=10)
>         4 => string '2017-07-20' (length=10)
>         'visit_reason' => string 'This visit occured for medication collection only' (length=49)
>         5 => string 'This visit occured for medication collection only' (length=49)
>         'consultation_type' => string 'MedicationCollection' (length=20)
>         6 => string 'MedicationCollection' (length=20)
>         'patient_weight' => string '0' (length=1)
>         7 => string '0' (length=1)
>         'patient_height' => string '0' (length=1)
>         8 => string '0' (length=1)
>         'visit_status' => string 'Inactive' (length=8)
>         9 => string 'Inactive' (length=8)
>         'clinic_id' => string '361' (length=3)
>         10 => string '361' (length=3)
>         'doctor_name' => string 'Abbas Nasser' (length=12)
>         11 => string 'Abbas Nasser' (length=12)
>         'nurse_name' => null
>         12 => null
>         'complication_name' => string 'Regular Medication Collection Visit' (length=35)
>         13 => string 'Regular Medication Collection Visit' (length=35)
>         'diagnosis_id' => string '86' (length=2)
>         14 => string '86' (length=2)
>         'consultation_result' => string 'medication collection' (length=21)
>         15 => string 'medication collection' (length=21)
>         'med_name' => string 'Isosorbide Dinitrate 10mg (Isordil 10mg) Tablets ' (length=49)
>         16 => string 'Isosorbide Dinitrate 10mg (Isordil 10mg) Tablets ' (length=49)
>         'given_quantity' => string '0' (length=1)
>         17 => string '0' (length=1)
>         'medication_collector' => string 'brother' (length=7)
>         18 => string 'brother' (length=7)

Comment: fetchAll return array of values so you nedd to use `<?php echo $res[0]['patient_id'] ?>`

Comment: check `var_dump($res);` and show us the output.I think it's an array having multiple values

Comment: Please check the edit at the end of the question to see the result of var dump

Comment: Best way to know your array structure is to write `echo "<pre>"; print_r($res);`, and then you can easily identify position of index to select them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
<?php if(count($res) >1){echo $res[0]['patient_id'];}else{echo $res['patient_id']; } ?>
```

Note:- this condition will check that array have more than one record or not. if yes then use 0 index, otherwise fetch directly.

Comment: But usually it was working in some cases as just `$res['patient_id']` why here not

Comment: when you have single record then only it will work.I have just changed my code to overcome both situation.

Comment: you need to change this: `count($res >1)` to: `count($res)>1`

Comment: @Rashid  thanks for pointing out.changed

Answer (score 1):

If you want single record then write `LIMIT 1` in your query.

and use

```
$execGetVisitProfile->fetch(); // will return single record
```

Comment: No. Sometimes I need all the arrays